# is the changelog used anywhere inside bloom?

Tags: ros, ros-release, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the instructions on the release page [here](http://ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseCatkinPackage), I've run the following commands:

```
catkin_generate_changelog
catkin_tag_changelog
catkin_prepare_release
bloom-release foo --track hydro --rosdistro hydro
```

After performing the release, I noticed that the updates to the changelog had not been committed to my upstream repo by any script. I assume I can commit then now to the development branch, and that the changelog itself is not used by bloom?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67032/is-the-changelog-used-anywhere-inside-bloom?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bloom will take the changelog and populate the debian changelog.  It won't break anything but you will not have all the information available for this release.  It's probably not worth a new release.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-07-12**:
@tfoote: Looks like you need to update your answer given recent failures on the build farm :).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-12**:
This is a regression in bloom.  It should be padding out empty changelogs if they aren't filled by the maintainers: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/171

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-07-12**:
Ah understood. I'll pay attention to committing the changelog till bloom 0.4.3 comes out.